# ActionMode touch events are passed through to the toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

In my activity I use the `Toolbar` (from appcompat) with a spinner instead of a title (defined in xml). The activity is not an `ActionBarActivity` so I don't use it as  a supportActionBar

When a selection occurs I start the `actionMode`, which is styled to be above the toolbar.

However, clicking on the title of the actionMode opens the underlying spinner's drop down menu. How can I "catch" the touch events on the actionMode's title to stop them from being passed through to the toolbar?

Comment: Are you using a custom style for the actionMode?

Comment: If you use `AppCompat`, then you have to use `ActionBarActivity, don't you?`

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution would be to put `yourspinner.setClickable(false);` when actionMode is opened and `yourspinner.setClickable(true);` when it is closed.

*EDIT*

you can also try to override the `actionMode`'s `onActionItemClicked`method to return `true`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.Callback.html#onActionItemClicked(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode, android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: This is also my current work around but I don't think this should be necessary.

Comment: @Evripidis Drakos return true does not help though :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to overload the onTouchEvent of your Toolbar. If your actionMode is true, true will be sent, and the touchEvent chain is stopped.

```
mToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
         return actionMode;
    }
 });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Seriously? No sane way of doing this? :-(

Comment: @DanieleRicci doesn't look like there is... I ended up disabling the spinner

Comment: The onTouch trick doesn't work with action items. I'll have to use a combination of both answers.